# Drawing water container with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not very good at JS even after reading the tutorial so I am asking for help here.

I think a jsfiddle would help.

I am trying to create a small box using JS and the box has green color filled from bottom to top when the "water container is full" When the water container is half the box is half green meaning half full. When the container is empty, no water, the JS drawn box is all empty with no green.

So in essence, I am using PHP to do some back-end computations that output values between 0 and 1000 indicating the fullness of a container in real life. 0 means the container is empty and 1000 means the container is fully filled with water.

Now to draw the GUI equivalent is what I am stuck on. How do I draw a box using JS that empties (green lowers) as the value PHP provides goes from 1000 to 0 (water empties)

Here is an example of what I am trying to make. So basically, PHP pulls from MySQL DB a value from 1000 to 0 and 1000 means completely green box and 0 means completely empty or grey box on GUI.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6642.png

PHP provides the values for the "fullness" of each box in the form of 0-1000 integers.

How do I draw this in JQuery?

I assume I will be using the Content Refresh option in HTML to refresh the page every 5-10 seconds so that the boxes appear to be changing in fullness as PHP provides updated data.

Here I am trying to create 3 divs with green background: http://jsfiddle.net/AAVT4/1/

So this way I can put these 3 divs inside another big div and do height-percentage changes on the 3 divs but I can't get the CSS right.

HTML

```
</cite>

<div class="hold"><div class="contain">
<div class="mpd1">This is box 1.</div>
<div class="mpd2">This is box 2.</div>
<div class="mpd3">This is box 3.</div></div></div>
<div class="corner"></div>
<div class="mpd"><a href="http://www.myspaceprodesigns.com"><img src="http://www.myspaceprodesigns.com/images/MPD.jpg" alt="myspace div generator" title="myspace div generator"></a></div>
<div class="comments">
<table><tr><td>
<table><tr><td>
```

CSS

```
<cite style="display:none">

</cite>

<style type="text/css">
.DivOverlayLayouts.com-div-generator{display:none}
body {
background-color:FFFFFF
}
.contain div {
background-color:76EE00;
color:FFFFFF;
font: 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
overflow:auto
}
a:link, a:active, a:visited, a.navbar:link, a.navbar:active, a.navbar:visited, a.man:link, a.man:active, a.man:visited, a:hover, a.navbar:hover, a.man:hover {
color:000000;
font: 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif
}
.mpd1{width:225px;height:600px;top:0;left:50px;position:absolute}
.mpd2{width:225px;height:600px;top:0;left:285px;position:absolute}
.mpd3{width:225px;height:600px;top:0;left:520px;position:absolute}.hold{background-color:transparent} 
.contain{left:50%;margin-left:-400px;top:150px;position:absolute;z-index:0;background-color:transparent;visibility:visible}
.corner{left:0;top:0;position:absolute;z-index:9;visibility:visible !important}
.mpd{left:50%;margin-left:-400px;top:0;position:absolute;z-index:9;visibility:visible !important}
.comments{display:none}
.contacttable,.profileinfo,.latestBlogEntry,.interestsAndDetails,.extendedNetwork,.orangetext15{display:none}
.bodyContent div div form{display:inline}
.bodyContent table table table{visibility:hidden}
a img{border:none}
td,form{margin:0;padding:0}
table,tr,td{background:transparent}
DivOverlayLayouts.com-additional-coding{display:none}
</style>
```

Comment: Normally the question-poster provides a jsfiddle with what he already got ;)  Have you tried using CSS (a div nested in a div with a height-percentage)?

Comment: @puredevotion I will give that a try right now. I never thought of using CSS. That is smart!

Comment: Here I tried to use JSfiddle to create 3 divs with green background but I just get white: 

http://jsfiddle.net/AAVT4/1/

Comment: You have no color because you missed the # in the color code. Here is your fiddle fixed a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/AAVT4/2/

Comment: @puredevotion, no not "normally", but it really helps. Alternatives is bootply, jsbin etc.

Comment: @MightyPork ah! that fixed it....Now I am trying to apporach of putting the 3 divs in another div and doing % height adjustments

Comment: I did that for you in the answer, you can build on top of that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your problem - showing the water:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AAVT4/3/

```
<div class="tank">
    <div class="water" style="height: 30%;"></div>
</div>

<div class="tank">
    <div class="water" style="height: 70%;"></div>
</div>

<div class="tank">
    <div class="water" style="height: 10%;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tank {
    /* size */
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;

    /* colors */
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: white;

    position: relative; /* to allow positioning the water at bottom */

    display: inline-block; /* so the div doesn't wrap */
    margin: 10px; /* space between divs */
}

.tank .water {
    position: absolute;

    /* color of water */
    background: blue;

    /* water position */
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That is just what I wanted! Thank you. Would have taken me half a day lol.